# why returned value difference between if-based test and lambda-based test

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, comparison

Can someone explain why a comparison in an if statement appears to be different when the same operator is used in a lambda?

Given the code below, it was my assumption the if statement comparison would exclude 18 unless explicitly included with the use of `<=`.

One thought was the def key function's explicitly returning `True` or `False`, but I haven't tested for that.

What should I know about this fundamental behaviour to avoid messing up?

If it matters, Python 3.6.9.

```
ages = [5, 12, 17, 18, 24, 32]

def fn(x):
    if x < 18:
        return False
    else:
        return True
# the key function is the first argument to 'filter', and the second is the list input 'ages'
# below, the lambda does not directly input the list, 'filter' picks up 'ages' and iterates to 'lambda', but, strangely, there is a difference of interpretation in the output between the def's if statement and the lambda key function in the use of comparison operators??? 
adults = filter(fn, ages)
print(list(adults))

# list is returned by way of list() wrapped expression
adults = list(filter(lambda _: (_>18), ages))
print(adults)
```

Which outputs:

```
def: [18, 24, 32]
lambda: [24, 32]
```

Comment: The two flip the bit on returning True or False to filter, but if you `>=`, or `<=` with the lambda you include or exclude as desired, but not so with the if? Does your answer explain that?

Comment: The first call is equivalent to `list(filter(lambda _: not(_<18), ages))`, which is equivalent to `list(filter(lambda _: (_>=18), ages))`. That is why 18 is included in the first list but not in the second.

Comment: The excellent answer above, which explains, to me, and by extension, why simply flipping the operators between the def and the lambda doesn't work, I removed the `not` condition by altering the result of the if test. This syncs the def with the lambda, and then the operators work as expected. So, `if x >=18: return True else: return False`. Thanks for the assist.